# Initializing an ArrayList within a constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

As part of an assignment I'm supposed to create a bunch of rectangles and put each of those objects within an `ArrayList`, which is to be initialized in a constructor. I think I've confused myself. Eclipse is telling me that I can't use `.add(new_rec)` with this object because it is of type (`Double`, `Double`). I assume because the ArrayList is simply `<Double>` this is causing some issue. Aside from that I think I'm misguided somewhere else, but I'm not sure where.

```
public class WhyWontThisWork {

        WhyWontThisWork(Double name, Double rec_name){
            Rectangle new_rec = new Rectangle(23.1,43.0);
            ArrayList<Double> name = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                name.add(new_rec);
            }
        }
}
```

...and the `Rectangle` class looks like...

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double length;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
```

Comment: the main reason is that a `rectangle` _is not_ a `double`, additionally, you have to give different names for `name`, they cannot be the same

Comment: also variable `name`already defined in the scope

Comment: @epoch Oops, my mistake on the naming sloppiness. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really quite simple- the type you need for name should be:

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

The generic type inside the <> represents what kinds of a thing you are adding to the ArrayList. If you need to store an array of double you can use  `ArrayList<Double>` if they are strings then `ArrayList<String>`

In your case you need to store a list of Rectangles so `ArrayList<Rectangle>` is your solution.

Comment: So the `<...>` is to be filled with any object? I'm confused on why `Rectangle` works here.

Comment: Updated with more explanation - hope this helps.

Comment: So if I created a class of, say, `Kittens` and I needed to fill an ArrayList with those objects would I declare `ArrayList<Kittens>`?

Comment: Exactly - this is what Java generics are for - giving you a type-safe way to implement algorithms (such as linked lists/array lists)  which are not specific to a particular data type.

Comment: Better use interfaces and not the concrete implementation class for `name`, i.e. `List<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();`

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList used need to be

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

As you are using the arrayList to save Rectangles not Doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Your arraylist must be of type Rectangle to be able to do this.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is right.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
name.add(new_rec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also parameter and ArrayList `name` is same,change it as below :

```
   WhyWontThisWork(Double nameDouble, Double rec_name){
                Rectangle new_rec = new Rectangle(23.1,43.0);
                ArrayList<Rectangle> name = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    name.add(new_rec);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `Rectangle` object to a `ArrayList` that holds `Double` objects. That is why you see the error. As pointed out in the other answers the likely best solution is to change the list to `ArrayList<Rectangle>`.

Maybe you should read a bit about **generics** in Java [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).